# error in code of timetable generator using genetic algorithm

Tags: c++, visual-studio, genetic-algorithm

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "Configuration.h"
#include "Professor.h"
#include "StudentsGroup.h"
#include "Course.h"
#include "Room.h"
#include "CourseClass.h"

Configuration Configuration::_instance;

// Frees used resources
Configuration::~Configuration()
{
    for( hash_map<int, Professor*>::iterator it = _professors.begin(); it != _professors.end(); it++ )
        delete ( *it ).second;

    for( hash_map<int, StudentsGroup*>::iterator it = _studentGroups.begin(); it != _studentGroups.end(); it++ )
        delete ( *it ).second;

    for( hash_map<int, Course*>::iterator it = _courses.begin(); it != _courses.end(); it++ )
        delete ( *it ).second;

    for( hash_map<int, Room*>::iterator it = _rooms.begin(); it != _rooms.end(); it++ )
        delete ( *it ).second;

    for( list<CourseClass*>::iterator it = _courseClasses.begin(); it != _courseClasses.end(); it++ )
        delete *it;
}

// Parse file and store parsed object
void Configuration::ParseFile(char* fileName)
{
    // clear previously parsed objects
    _professors.clear();
    _studentGroups.clear();
    _courses.clear();
    _rooms.clear();
    _courseClasses.clear();

    Room::RestartIDs();

    // open file
    ifstream input( fileName );

    string line;
    while( input.is_open() && !input.eof() )
    {
        // get lines until start of new object is not found
        getline( input, line );
        TrimString( line );

        // get type of object, parse obect and store it

        if( line.compare("#prof") == 0 )
        {
            Professor* p = ParseProfessor( input );
            if( p )
                _professors.insert( pair<int, Professor*>( p->GetId(), p ) );
        }
        else if( line.compare("#group") == 0 )
        {
            StudentsGroup* g = ParseStudentsGroup( input );
            if( g )
                _studentGroups.insert( pair<int, StudentsGroup*>( g->GetId(), g ) );
        }
        else if( line.compare("#course") == 0 )
        {
            Course* c = ParseCourse( input );
            if( c )
                _courses.insert( pair<int, Course*>( c->GetId(), c ) );
        }
        else if( line.compare("#room") == 0 )
        {
            Room* r = ParseRoom( input );
            if( r )
                _rooms.insert( pair<int, Room*>( r->GetId(), r ) );
        }
        else if( line.compare("#class") == 0 )
        {
            CourseClass* c = ParseCourseClass( input );
            if( c )
                _courseClasses.push_back( c );
        }
    }

    input.close();

    _isEmpty = false;
}

// Reads professor's data from config file, makes object and returns pointer to it
// Returns NULL if method cannot parse configuration data
Professor* Configuration::ParseProfessor(ifstream& file)
{
    int id = 0;
    string name;

    while( !file.eof() )
    {
        string key, value;

        // get key - value pair
        if( !GetConfigBlockLine( file, key, value ) )
            break;

        // get value of key
        if( key.compare("id") == 0 )
            id = atoi( value.c_str() );
        else if( key.compare("name") == 0 )
            name = value;
    }

    // make object and return pointer to it
    return id == 0 ? NULL : new Professor( id, name );
}

// Reads professor's data from config file, makes object and returns pointer to it
// Returns NULL if method cannot parse configuration data
StudentsGroup* Configuration::ParseStudentsGroup(ifstream& file)
{
    int id = 0, number = 0;
    string name;

    while( !file.eof() )
    {
        string key, value;

        // get key - value pair
        if( !GetConfigBlockLine( file, key, value ) )
            break;

        // get value of key
        if( key.compare("id") == 0 )
            id = atoi( value.c_str() );
        else if( key.compare("name") == 0 )
            name = value;
        else if( key.compare("size") == 0 )
            number = atoi( value.c_str() );
    }

    // make object and return pointer to it
    return id == 0 ? NULL : new StudentsGroup( id, name, number );
}

// Reads course's data from config file, makes object and returns pointer to it
// Returns NULL if method cannot parse configuration data
Course* Configuration::ParseCourse(ifstream& file)
{
    int id = 0;
    string name;

    while( !file.eof() )
    {
        string key, value;

        // get key - value pair
        if( !GetConfigBlockLine( file, key, value ) )
            break;

        // get value of key
        if( key.compare("id") == 0 )
            id = atoi( value.c_str() );
        else if( key.compare("name") == 0 )
            name = value;
    }

    // make object and return pointer to it
    return id == 0 ? NULL : new Course( id, name );
}

// Reads rooms's data from config file, makes object and returns pointer to it
// Returns NULL if method cannot parse configuration data
Room* Configuration::ParseRoom(ifstream& file)
{
    int number = 0;
    bool lab = false;
    string name;

    while( !file.eof() )
    {
        string key, value;

        // get key - value pair
        if( !GetConfigBlockLine( file, key, value ) )
            break;

        // get value of key
        if( key.compare("name") == 0 )
            name = value;
        else if( key.compare("lab") == 0 )
            lab = value.compare( "true" ) == 0;
        else if( key.compare("size") == 0 )
            number = atoi( value.c_str() );
    }

    // make object and return pointer to it
    return number == 0 ? NULL : new Room( name, lab, number );
}

// Reads class' data from config file, makes object and returns pointer to it
// Returns NULL if method cannot parse configuration data
CourseClass* Configuration::ParseCourseClass(ifstream& file)
{
    int pid = 0, cid = 0, dur = 1;
    bool lab = false;

    list<StudentsGroup*> groups;

    while( !file.eof() )
    {
        string key, value;

        // get key - value pair
        if( !GetConfigBlockLine( file, key, value ) )
            break;

        // get value of key
        if( key.compare("professor") == 0 )
            pid = atoi( value.c_str() );
        else if( key.compare("course") == 0 )
            cid = atoi( value.c_str() );
        else if( key.compare("lab") == 0 )
            lab = value.compare( "true" ) == 0;
        else if( key.compare("duration") == 0 )
            dur = atoi( value.c_str() );
        else if( key.compare("group") == 0 )
        {
            StudentsGroup* g = GetStudentsGroupById( atoi( value.c_str() ) );
            if( g )
                groups.push_back( g );
        }
    }

    // get professor who teaches class and course to which this class belongs
    Professor* p = GetProfessorById( pid );
    Course* c = GetCourseById( cid );

    // does professor and class exists
    if( !c || !p )
        return NULL;

    // make object and return pointer to it
    CourseClass* cc = new CourseClass( p, c, groups, lab, dur );
    return cc;
}

// Reads one line (key - value pair) from configuration file
bool Configuration::GetConfigBlockLine(ifstream& file, string& key, string& value)
{
    string line;

    // end of file
    while( !file.eof() )
    {
        // read line from config file
        getline( file, line );
        TrimString( line );

        // end of object's data 
        if( line.compare( "#end" ) == 0 )
            return false;

        size_t p = line.find( '=' );
        if( p != string.npos )
        {
            // key
            key = line.substr( 0, p );
            TrimString( key );

            // value
            value = line.substr( p + 1, line.length() );
            TrimString( value );

            // key - value pair read successfully
            return true;
        }
    }

    // error
    return false;
}

// Removes blank characters from beginning and end of string
string& Configuration::TrimString(string& str)
{
    string::iterator it;
    for( it = str.begin(); it != str.end() && isspace( *it ); it++ )
        ;
    str.erase( str.begin(), it );

    string::reverse_iterator rit;
    for( rit = str.rbegin(); rit != str.rend() && isspace( *rit ) ; rit++ )
        ;
    str.erase( str.begin() + ( str.rend() - rit ), str.end() );

    return str;
}
```

Error   1   error C1083: Cannot open precompiled header file: 'Debug\GaSchedule.pch': No such file or directory c:\users\rehana\desktop\gaschedulesource\gaschedule\gaschedule\stdafx.cpp   5   1   GaSchedule
Error   2   error C1083: Cannot open precompiled header file: 'Debug\GaSchedule.pch': No such file or directory c:\users\rehana\desktop\gaschedulesource\gaschedule\gaschedule\algorithm\configuration.cpp  2   1   GaSchedule
    3   IntelliSense: cannot open source file "StdAfx.h"    c:\users\rehana\desktop\gaschedulesource\gaschedule\gaschedule\algorithm\configuration.cpp  2   1   GaSchedule

This is a project which generates timetable using genetic algorithm and we are tryig to run it on visual studio. It is giving error as above mentioned. Please help

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [***Minimal***, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Disable using precomiled header in menu project/properties/c++/pre-compiled headers